# Restful API: How to display specific data in Node/Express app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I am building a simple Node/Express app to login a user. Before user can login the app must check if the email provided exists in the database.
The structure of my app is like this:
* db/data.js
* app.js // server
I want to login a user

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    email: 'xyz@xyz.com',
    fist_name: 'hekw',
    last_name: 'xyz',
    password: 'usr$@',


  },
];

export default data;
```

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import data from './db/data';

// set up the express app
const app = express();

// Parse incoming requests data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

/**
 * Sign in a user
 * @param {object} req
 * @param {object} res
 */
app.post(`/login`, (req, res) => {

  const findUserByEmail = (email) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        return data[i]['email'] === email ? true : false;
    }
  };

  if (findUserByEmail(req.body.email)) {
    return res.status(409).send({
      success: false,
      message: 'email already exists',
      //findUserByEmail(req.body.email)
      //data,

    });
  }

const port = 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  // console.log(`The server running on port ${PORT}`);
});

export default app;
```

I tried but I couldn't display info of a signed user. How can I achieve it?
This is what I need:

```
"status":"success"
"data": {
"id": 1,
"email":"xyz@xyz.com",
"first_name": "hekw",
"last_name": "xyz",
"password": "usr$@"
}
```

**Edit**
I've implemented the code below, but I want now to check for both email and password.

```
const findUserByEmail = (email) => data.find(user => user.email === email);
const foundUser = findUserByEmail(req.body.email);

  if (!foundUser) {
    return res.status(404).send({
      status: 'error',
      error: 'user does not exist, register first',
    });
  }

  if (foundUser) {
// if password OK then diplay success message. How do I access pwd field here?
    return res.status(200).send({
      status: 'success',
      data: foundUser,
    });
  }
```

Comment: can you show your html form? Are you sure you are sending post? What is the response when you make the request?

Comment: I am using Postman

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I highly recommend using the MVC pattern and create a model for each separate data model. Also, an encryption method such as Bcrypt to encrypt the passwords before storing them to the database and using a token-based approach to handle user authentication.

For the purpose of the example, I provide a solution with the JWT and Bcrypt to help understand the process better, also for people who are looking for a more detailed answer. We can pass a middleware into routes to check the user is authenticated or not then fetch the proper data for the user.

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const router = express.Router();

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

// This user model can be replaced with your data file, in your sample
const User = require('../models/userModel');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Always return JSON for the rest api

// Awlays set headers to controll the access
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
});

// This is the user controller, below return it inside the route
const loginUserController = (req, res) => {
User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }) // find just one record by the email received from the user
    .exec() // Use this to make a promise
    .then(user => {
        if (user.length < 1) { // check if the user found
            return res.status(401).json({ // Check if email is not valid
                message: 'Authentication Failed! Wrong login information used!'
            })
        }
        // If status code is not 401 and user is found, then compare the password with DB version and pass "err" and "success" parameters 
        // user.password is the db password
        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, (err, success) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(401).json({
                    message: 'Authentication Failed! Wrong login information used!'
                })
            }
            if (success) {
                // Then we sign JWT if password matched
                // process.env.JWT_KEY is our server jwt token
                const token = jwt.sign({
                    email: user.email,
                    userId: user._id
                }, process.env.JWT_KEY, {
                        expiresIn: '2d' // we can set the expire date (see th e docs for more info)
                    });
                // Finally we return our token to store into user's browser cookie 
                // or we can just return the data, but its better to use jwt token and use it everywhere you want to get user data
                return res.status(200).json({
                    message: 'Welcome to My App!',
                    data: user
                    token
                });
            }
            // Here we return another 401 if the were no err or success
            res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Authentication Failed! Wrong login information used!'
            })
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // Use can create an error controller and put a switch inside of it to check response status code then return proper message
        errorController(req, res, res.status, 'ANY'); 
    })
 }

// Finally we use our router to post and return login controller
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    return loginUserController(req, res);
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

There are more advanced configurations, but for simplicity of the example, I provided a simple way to do the correct way (in my opinion). Hope it help.

**Packages used in this example**

- [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken)
- [Bcrypt](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js)

Comment: Thank you for this. I am planning to use this after refactoring of my code. For now I wanted just something (very) simple to pass my tests. I am using TDD.

Comment: You're welcome, so you solved the issue or not? You just need to replace my bcrypt section with a simple password compare function. Password matching should be right after email is verified, after `if (user.length < 1)`. If it's not clear I write another example for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working. Following will not find the user object in your data array.

```js
const findUserByEmail = (email) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        return data[i]['email'] === email ? true : false;
    }
  };
```

You can find the user like this:

```js
const findUserByEmail = (email) => data.find((datum) => datum.email === email);
```

*Assuming* you are sending a POST request with email set correctly. You can use the following code to achieve the result you want:

```js
const findUser = (email, pass) => data.find((datum) => datum.email === email && datum.password === pass);
let foundUser = findUser(req.body.email, req.body.password);
if (foundUser) {
    return res.status(200).json({
        "status":"success"
        "data": foundUser
    });
}

res.status(404).json({
    "status": "Not Found"
    "data": foundUser
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried to implement as you can see above. But I see that it would be better to check for couple of things: email and password must all be OK.

Comment: You can also add the condition for password. Change the code as you like. What is the password variable you are sending from postman?

Comment: ```password``` (```req.body.password```)

Comment: Added a password check there as well. Check out the new code.